# Microsoft Outlook 2010 Rule to Match Against HTML Source?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, phishing

A client receives phishing e-mails with link manipulation: the displayed text for a link (the text between the anchor "a" tags) shows a random safe URL, while the actual URL in the HTML source links to the phishers' site. For example:

```
<a href={Phishing URL}> {Variable Safe URL} </a>
```

{Phishing URL} remains the same between all the e-mails; nothing else seems consistent enough to filter by.

In Microsoft Outlook 2010, I attempted to create a rule to automatically delete messages containing {Phishing URL}, above, in the body text.

However, Microsoft Outlook 2010 fails to identify and delete the e-mail when I run tests, which leads me to believe it only matches the visible text.

How do I create a Microsoft Outlook 2010 rule which matches {Phishing URL} in the e-mail's HTML source?

Comment: This is for Outlook 2007, but it should be more or less the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865500/regular-expression-rules-in-outlook-2007